# Hololens Re-scanning the environment using spatial understanding

Tags: hololens

I'm using spatial understanding to scan the environment and generate the spatial meshes. (According to the example in the HoloToolkit spatial understanding example)

After generating the meshes initially, i want to have an option to re-scan the environment again(removing the old meshes and regenerating new meshes). Is there any possible ways where i can achieve this. Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to restart spatial understanding, a place you could start is by deleting the meshes (they are all parented in a gameobject) and deleting the spatialunderstanding components then programmatically recreating them and configuring them.

Answer (score 0):

if you use voice commands from mixedrealitytoolkit-unity (holotookit-unity) you can bind the scanning to a voice command (for example "scan") every time you call scan it should start scanning.

I'm not sure how to delete old meshes completely. but I don't see a point in deleting them. If the environment updated it will delete unnecessary meshes automatically. Im sure there is a command to delete all meshes somewhere in toolkit though. I recommend to check github for that.